# Twitter Bootstrap Button Dropdown not dropping down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a simple dropdown button from the Twitter Bootstrap. **However, it's isn't showing the dropdown options**. The code is below and here is a link to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nunos/DjHyQ/11/

**EDIT:** found out the problem. I was including the `bootstrap.js` in the `<head>`. Once I changed that line to the `<body>` as the Twiiter Bootstrap Documentation actually says, it worked right away. I never thought there was a difference in scripts being included in the `<head>` or in the `<body>`. Now I know!

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>             
    </div>
</div>
​
```

Comment: ..And your fiddle didnt work since you used `mootools 1.4.5` causing `TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined`, here is a forked working version using `jquery 1.7.2` http://jsfiddle.net/VG7G7/

Answer (score 1):

Well,  the fiddle you posted isn't working because you have not selected jquery (which is required for bootstrap widgets) as your framework (the selection box is on the sidebar on the right hand side of the page). Are you loading jquery in your actual code?

Comment: You are completely right, I forgot to include it on the fiddle, but I am including it on my project (tested!). Can't really understand why it doesn't show the options then...

Comment: That is odd: any chance you could post the page header so we can see what you are loading?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqEJz/), with jQuery and Bootstrap loaded

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>             
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did youchange anything else, besides including the jQuery in the fiddle?

Comment: I changed the button class I don't think you had dropdown-toggle

Comment: I had.. The code I copy and paste from the working fiddle into my project just doesn't show me the dropdown options. And in the same exact page I have a jQuery ui progress bar working, so jQuery is definitely included. Really puzzled about this right now...

Answer (score 0):

You must add a class 
    dropdown 
to the "ul" element.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>             
    </div>
</div>
```

​ You can check here it works. http://jsfiddle.net/DjHyQ/13/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but, if you try it with or without the 'dropdown' option on the ul it works just the same. http://jsfiddle.net/nunos/DjHyQ/14/

Comment: So the only problem in your fiddle was that you were not including jQuery.. try this http://jsfiddle.net/nunos/DjHyQ/11/ by including jQuery and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you must forget to link Jquery.js or Bootstrap.js in your head, they are both needed. I have this problem myself and fix it with add these two script link

Comment: The post already said "never thought there was a difference in scripts being included in the <head> or in the <body>", so this answer is a little redundant.